# where to add php extension name to compile it with other extensions

Tags: php, php-extension

I have created sample php extension using ext_skel command tool.

when I try `./configure --help` from php base folder, my extension does not show up there.

where should I add/enable my extension name so that it will be appeared on `./configure --help`  of php.

Note: I can compile it separately from `php/ext/extname`  folder, but I want it compile with from php base with other extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these steps :-

```
:~/cvs/php4/ext:> ./ext_skel --extname=my_module
Creating directory my_module
Creating basic files: config.m4 .cvsignore my_module.c php_my_module.h CREDITS EXPERIMENTAL tests/001.phpt my_module.php [done].
```

To use your new extension, you will have to execute the following steps:

1. $ cd ..
2. $ vi ext/my_module/config.m4
3. $ ./buildconf
4. $ ./configure --[with|enable]-my_module
5. $ make
6. $ ./php -f ext/my_module/my_module.php
7. $ vi ext/my_module/my_module.c
8. $ make

Repeat steps 3-6 until you are satisfied with ext/my_module/config.m4 and
step 6 confirms that your module is compiled into PHP. Then, start writing
code and repeat the last two steps as often as necessary.

You need to run ./buildconf command that will add your extension to the PHP extensions list. After this, you will be able to see your extension by the ./configure -help command.

Please follow document http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php for more clarification.